# Writing control code on WAGO PFC200 PLC in C/C++ languages?

Tags: plc

I have a WAGO PFC200 750-8206 and was wondering if I can write my control logic code in C/C++. I know that WAGO uses codesys runtime and codesys only supports IEC languages, but WAGO claims that their PLCs support C/C++ programs. What I am not sure about is if they mean C/C++ applications in Linux or actual control code running inside codeys?

copy/paste from WAGO:

"Alternatively, the runtime environment can also be completely created by its own “C/C++” programs, permitting access to both the internal bus, as well as MODBUS, CAN and PROFIBUS."

https://www.wago.com/global/embedded-linux

Comment: Yes, you can do that in C. But this remain sort of a mistery. I was looking for the same ansver for some time, but closest I could get is SSH my PLC and work as usual with linux system. I did not get a guide how to access WAGO bus.

Answer (score 0):

Wago provide an SDK that will permit you access to the IO. Use [this link](https://www.wago.com/global/requestDirectDownload?downloadFile=swreg_linux) to apply for access to the SDK